# Paddington Bear Choppertar

Tags: discussion, fun, bears, many-bears, gravatar

Many of our top users seem to have avatars with a picture of themselves in a car with what appears to me to be Paddington Bear:
[image]
 [image]

So what is the story behind this?

Comment: The Paddington Bear was also childhood friend of mine. One day I removed his boots only to find that his left leg was significantly shorter than the right. This caused my young mind a significant amount of grief, as I tried to imagine how this could have happened.

From then on, I could never play with Paddington freely. I was constantly drawn to removing his boots and examining his deformity.  Many years on, I became a Sysadmin.  Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: Corrected tags for clarity

Comment: Oh, crap... I've been out of town for a few days and not checking meta. I missed this whole thing!

Answer (score 33):

Erm...my fault.

There's a theme park near where I live called 'Adventure Wonderland', I was forced to go about 5 years ago with another local family. Well it was beyond crappy - I was SO bored, then out of the corner of my eye I saw the Paddington 'Kiddy Ride' (that's the official term for those things apparently). As a kid I'd loved the books and even went on 'Junior Mastermind' on the BBC answering questions about them (came first on specialist subject but came second overall by one point after the general knowledge round - not that I'm bitter or overly competitive about it). I'd always been fond of Paddington so I cheered myself up by having that photo taken.

I get lots of photos taken for work stuff with me all 'suited-up' but the avatar I like for this site (and a couple of others) is that one of me with Paddington - as I feel it conveys something about me that many others don't.

Anyway cut to last week or so when EvanA pops up, he'd seen an almost identical ride near him and thought it would be funny to sit in it and get a photo. Well it worked and I was simply delighted by it, since then others have very nicely made their own. I am in the process of finding and buying a ride such as that which I hope to ship (and possibly abandon) at a future SF-related event.

So there you go.

Comment: Plus you were having a bad day the other day so I changed mine to help cheer you up with becoming a gravatar-meme :-)

Comment: Well, that, and I owed him for a little bit of advice @Chopper3 gave regarding what kind of hat to wear in Boston...not funny! I know nothing about sports...

Comment: I told another friend that Yankee caps are made in South Boston and that he should wear one, smiling and pointing at it wherever he went went there - he was physically thrown out of a bar :)

Comment: Okay, that's kind of funny, I suppose.

Comment: The idea of shipping a Paddington ride to a SF event was actually my idea.. :P

Answer (score 27):

I did't buy [Chopper3's story](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1850/paddington-bear-avatar/1852#1852) (*"five years ago, bla bla"* ...). So I went to his company's car park and discovered this little secret: **IT'S HIS REGULAR CAR!!!**

I took this picture (exhibit 'A'):

[image: Paddington Bear car]

Comment: haha - that'd give me better mileage than my real car for certain

Answer (score 24):

Rogues gallery

[image: Chopper3][image: Bart Silverstrim][image: ChrisS][image: Evan Anderson][image: Iain][image: ITHedgeHog][image: Jacob][image: Kyle Brandt][image: Michael Loman][image: Scott Pack][image: Tom O'Connor][image: Wesley David][image: Zoredachee][image: voretaq7]
[image: sam][image: Small Clanger][image: Nixpho][image: wfaulk][image: Holocryptic]
[image: MikeyB][image: Ben Pilbrow][image: jscott][image: Inception][image: tombull89]

Comment: "Have you seen these users? Wanted for impersonating an officer of the highest order. Please dial 999 if you encounter them. They are considered unarmed and extremely contagious."

Comment: Ahh, crap... I got the steering wheel turned the wrong way... (and I couldn't find a red car, either... >grumble<)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Separated at birth]

Sir.

I could not help but be struck by the similarity between Chopper3 and Evan Anserson. I wonder if they are related.

Yours etc,

Iain

With apologies to [Private Eye's lookalikes](http://www.private-eye.co.uk/sections.php?section_link=lookalikes&lookalike=194&)

Comment: They must be similar. I think the labels are reversed...?

Comment: @BartSilverstrim: It's deliberate, I guess you have to have read Private Eve to get it.

Comment: Ah, I get it now...

Comment: I think I'm much fatter :)

Answer (score 15):

Revenge of the choptar meme.

[image]
Photo by: https://serverfault.com/users/16732/tom-oconnor
Original Question: [Two servers using same name servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/297756/2-servers-using-same-name-servers)

Comment: I just noticed that my self. Getting crazy out there!

Comment: @Nixphoe - Getting? **GETTING**?? *insane cackle*

Answer (score 7):

We can't answer that question until you have a Paddington Bear choppertar...

Comment: -1 for peer pressure and general tomfoolery.

Comment: Jokes on you. My name's not Tom. :-p

Answer (score 3):

For posterity.  I couldn't zoom out enough, but Bart's juuuuuust offscreen at the top.

[image]

Comment: Even worse, it doesn't appear that SE links out to a full-res image. :(

Comment: Right click -> View Image

Answer (score 3):

There is only one appropriate response to all of this tomfoolery: Additional tomfoolery in Unicode.

Comment: Nice... square.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Well, SOMEONE doesn't have full Unicode support on his workstation! http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U1F43B/Bear_Face

Comment: Weird. It doesn't show up in any of the fonts I tried.

Comment: also at some point my OS X unicode font got upgraded: It's a cartoon bearface now, not line-art...