# We're under attack.. by bears

Tags: discussion, bears, many-bears

[Two servers using same name servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/297756/2-servers-using-same-name-servers)

There are many bears.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1850/paddington-bear-choppertar

Comment: It's downright unbearable.

Comment: It's just good clean fun (until someone nicks a Paddington Bear ride from their local amusement park).

Comment: @Voretaq7 Are you thinking what I'm thinking?

Comment: @WesleyDavid - ABSOLUTELY NOT. NO. No. no. (maybe. (a little bit.))

Comment: @Voretaq7 I'll be around with the van at midnight.